# Counting items from a text file and returning results from another text file

Tags: c#, arrays

```
//Declare Class-level Array here
    private string[] Worldseries = new string[115];

    private void frmWorldseries_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Form Load Method (Need to write this code)


        //REad the winners file and store each record in an array
        StreamReader InputWinners;

        InputWinners = File.OpenText("Worldseries.txt");
        //Loop to read each record and store in Array
        int subscript = 0;
        while (!InputWinners.EndOfStream)
        {
            //Read a record and store record in array
            Worldseries[subscript] = InputWinners.ReadLine();
            //Increment subscript
            subscript++;
        }

        //Read the teams names file and store each record in a list box
        StreamReader InputTeams;

        InputTeams = File.OpenText("Teams.txt");
        //Loop to read each record and add to listbox
        while (!InputTeams.EndOfStream)
        {
            listTeams.Items.Add(InputTeams.ReadLine());
        }

        //Close both files
        InputWinners.Close();
        InputTeams.Close();
    }

    private void btnCountWins_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I'm having an issue with writing the code for counting up the number of wins. I need to double check to make sure a team has been selected. If no team name was selected in the ListBox, display an error message and return. I need an if statement to check this.

I also need to set up a loop that will loop through every entry in the WorldSeriesWinners array. For each entry in the array, if the name matches the name the user selected, add 1 to a counter. After the loop completes, display the number of wins.

I'm new to writing code and would greatly appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: FYI, the `System.IO.File` class has a lot of static methods that can really shorten the code needed to read and write files. For example, `Worldseries = File.ReadAllLines("Worldseries.txt");` replaces the first 6 lines of code.

Comment: So your question is "How to check if an item is selected in a ListBox"? Did you know that a `ListBox` has a [`SelectedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem?view=netframework-4.8) property?

Comment: `foreach(var winner in Worldseries) { if (winner == userSelectedName) userWinCount++; }` Or simply: `int userWinCount = Worldseries.Count(ws => ws == userSelectedName);`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a bit differently. I would create a dictionary instead of an array:

```
Dictionary<string, int> worldSeries = new Dictionary<string, int>();

private void frmWorldseries_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    foreach (string s in readText)
    {
        if (worldSeries.ContainsKey(s)) 
        {
            worldSeries[s]++;
        }
        else 
        {
            worldSeries.Add(s, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the button event:

```
if (listTeams.SelectedIndex == -1) {
    MessageBox.Show("Please select team");
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Your team won {worldSeries[listTeams.SelectedText].ToString()} times");
}
```

By doing that you're only looping once over your list, hence providing better performance.